# Adding a close button to the middle top edge of the modal

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap modal and I put a slightly overshot button on the edge. Everything looking perfect but I need to center this button.
[image: Center]

Another problem is when browser window changed; closing button is stays fixed, button need following to modal.

[image]

So When I add to snippet I realized button pulling to bottom;

[image]

Here my snippet;

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Orh</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .modal-default-close {
            margin: 0;
          
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            right: 48%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 23px;
            background-color: red;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 40px;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 10;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;

        }
        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {

            border-radius: 25px !important;
        }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered " role="document">
        <button type="button" class="btn modal-default-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
style="  margin-top:-0.21em;"                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                <h4 class="font-weight-light mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h4>
                <button class="btn btn-success m-3 ">Go</button>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

       <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(() => {
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    
    
        })
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `right: calc(50% - 15px);` - 15px being half width of your icon

Comment: @MrT can you apply your suggestion in snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parent position relative and adjust the top and right(i changed it to left) properties. This way your button will be in top center of your modal box regardless the size of the modal or the button itself.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Orh</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>

        .modal-content {
          position: relative;
        }
   

        .modal-default-close {
            margin: 0;
          
            position: absolute;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 23px;
            background-color: red;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 40px;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 10;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;

            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        }
        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {

            border-radius: 25px !important;
        }



    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered " role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="btn modal-default-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span style="margin-top:-0.21em;" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                <h4 class="font-weight-light mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h4>
                <button class="btn btn-success m-3 ">Go</button>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

       <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(() => {
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    
    
        })
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I click expand snippet; button is outside at the modal

Comment: I try this code in my computer but not worked https://imgur.com/YdyHA6o

Comment: I edited my snippet. I rearranged your html so button is now inside .modal-content with position relative